# How can I add my Firefox and Chrome history to Windows Search

Tags: windows-7, firefox, windows-search

How can I add my browsing history to Windows Search (in Windows 7)?  Internet Explorer History is included by default, but I use Firefox or Chrome.

---

EDIT:  If there's no way to do this yet, it should be possible to write something, since there seems to be an API for Windows Search.  More detail in the [Windows Search Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee872109(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's interesting that *any* search app in Linux has this function :-/.

Answer (score 5):

At least as regarding Firefox :

Firefox keeps the history in the database places.sqlite, which is an SQLite database. One would therefore need to write a general filter for SQLite databases for Windows Desktop Search (gigantic project!), or at least a specific one for places.sqlite.

The problem is that the structure of places.sqlite is not quite published. Also, with the rapid development of Firefox, this remains a fast-moving target.

In conclusion: While writing such a filter is certainly possible, the required investment is very large. Also, without frequent updates, the filter will fast become unusable.